# Prime number checker isnt giving accurate output

Tags: python, primes

I'm trying to make a code with one function that'll check for prime numbers in an array and it keeps saying that 33 is a prime number. What's wrong with my code:

```
def primes_nums(array):
    prime = []
    for i in array:
        for x in range(2, (i-1)):
            if i%x == 0:
                print(i,' is not a prime number')
                break
            else:
                prime.append(i)
                break
    return prime
pass
print(primes_nums([12, 33, 44, 89]))
```

The output comes out as:

```
12  is not a prime number
44  is not a prime number
[33, 89]
```

Comment: Go through it one step at a time. If `i%2` is not 0, then what does the code say should happen?

Comment: Beside the point, but what's that `pass` doing there? It does literally nothing. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: @wjandrea: mabe it's meant to trick `pytest` into not raising any problems :-)